# Linked List Not Working Properly

Tags: c++, linked-list

Here is my code

```
struct Node{
    char* isbn;
    char* author;
    char* title;
    char* copyright;
    char* genre;
    bool status;
    Node* next;
};

struct LinkedList {
Node* head; // This is the starting pointer of Linked List
LinkedList(){
    head = NULL;
}

void insertAtHead(char* a, char* b, char* c, char* d, char* e, bool f){
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->isbn = a;
    // etc. assigning information
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}

void display(){
    int i = 1;
    Node* it = head;
    while (it != NULL){
        // display book info
        it = it->next;
        i++;
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
};

int main(){
    LinkedList LL;
    int x;
    char a1[10] = "";
    char a2[25] = "";
    char a3[25] = "";
    char a4[15] = "";
    char a5[15] = "";
    bool a6 = 0;
do{
    cout << "\n======================================\n";
    cout << "1) Insert Book At Head.\n";
    cout << "2) Display All Books.\n";
    cout << "3) Exit.\n";
    cout << "======================================\n";
    cin >> x;

switch(x){
case 1:{
    cout << "Enter ISBN: "; cin >> a1;
    cout << "Enter The Author's Name: "; cin >> a2;
    cout << "Enter The Book Title: "; cin >> a3;
    cout << "Enter The CopyRights: "; cin >> a4;
    cout << "Enter The Book Genre: "; cin >> a5;
    cout << "Enter The Status Of Book: "; cin >> a6;

    LL.insertAtHead(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6);
    break;
    }
case 2:
    LL.display();
    break;
case 3:
    break;
}
}while(x!=3);
    return 0;
}
```

The Problem is That When i insert a book using case 1 of switch it inserts a book in 
the linked list with the given data but when i enter a new book the previously saved book
is overwritten by new book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the linked list which is not working.  It's the way you assign the values.  You givie it adress of your input buffers (which are overwritten at each reading) and you store this adress in your node.

You have to make a copy of your buffers (using the old C-way strdup()). 
I'd suggest a better approach:  consider the use of C++ strings.

It's suffichent to `#include <string>` and update your struct into:

```
struct Node{
    string isbn;
    string author;
    string title;
    string copyright;
    string genre;
    bool status;
    Node* next;
};
```

As strings understand correctly the assignment from char*, it wll generate its own copy, not realying anymore on your buffers.  It'll be better though to consider replacing char* with strings in all your code.